# Umbraco upgrade issue with RTE & uSync & Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm pretty new to Umbraco an I've just attempted to **upgraded from version 7.1.1 to the latest 7.2.6**. I all seemed fine until I noticed that the RTE stopped working. Then I deleted the umbraco.config file and the TEMP folder.

Since then I keep getting this error message:

```
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.cmsMacroProperty' with unique index 'IX_cmsMacroProperty_Alias'. The duplicate key value is (11, FormGuid).
The statement has been terminated.

[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.cmsMacroProperty' with unique index 'IX_cmsMacroProperty_Alias'. The duplicate key value is (11, FormGuid).
The statement has been terminated.]
   jumps.umbraco.usync.uSync.RunSync() +687
   jumps.umbraco.usync.uSync.DoOnStart() +118
   Umbraco.Core.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach(IEnumerable`1 items, Action`1 action) +148
   Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager.Complete(Action`1 afterComplete) +116
   Umbraco.Web.WebBootManager.Complete(Action`1 afterComplete) +95
   Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase.StartApplication(Object sender, EventArgs e) +223

[HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.cmsMacroProperty' with unique index 'IX_cmsMacroProperty_Alias'. The duplicate key value is (11, FormGuid).
The statement has been terminated.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +588
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +322
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +452

[HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.cmsMacroProperty' with unique index 'IX_cmsMacroProperty_Alias'. The duplicate key value is (11, FormGuid).
The statement has been terminated.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +646
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +778
```

Being new to Umbraco I find it hard to approach this exception and resolve the issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the initial error, I think you might need to update to the latest version of uSync. To see if that's the case, remove the uSync DLL from your bin folder and see if everything starts working. If it does, you just need to grab the latest version of uSync and use that instead of the current one!